# I need to add new items into my SQL table and update old ones

Tags: mysql, sql

This might be a stupid question but it honestly has me stumped.

I have an existing table which I want to update with new items. However if the old items are altered elsewhere then I want this to update automatically as well.

I have set the $eid as being a unique identifier so the tables wont be duplicated. I use this to add in new items.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `notification` (`nid` ,`eid` ,`subject` ,`active` ,`date`)VALUES (NULL , '$eid[$i]', '$subject[$i]',  '$active[$i]', '$eventdate[$i]')");
```

With my second query, I am trying to update the existing tables with the current updated information.

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `notification` SET `nid`=NULL,`eid`='$eid[$i]',`subject`='$subject[$i]',`active`='$active[$i]',`date`='$eventdate[$i]' WHERE `active` = 0");
```

However this second query just doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More details on error thrown by the MySQL?

However, if the column `nid` is your primary key, it cannot be `NULL`.

If you do not want to update it, just skip it in the update query:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `notification` SET `eid`='$eid[$i]',
`subject`='$subject[$i]',`active`='$active[$i]',`date`='$eventdate[$i]' 
WHERE `active` = 0");
```

Comment: I figured out the solution thanks to your help.

The second query needed to be...

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `notification` SET `subject`='$subject[$i]',`active`='$active[$i]',`date`='$eventdate[$i]' WHERE `eid` = $eid[$i]");

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE notification SET nid= '',eid='".$eid[$i]."',subject='".$subject[$i]."',active='".$active[$i]."',date='".$eventdate[$i]."' WHERE active = '0'");
```